# Lex Yacc, should i tokenize character literals?

Tags: yacc, lex

I know, poorly worded question not sure how else to ask though. 
I always seem to end up in the error branch regardless of what i'm entering and can't figure out where i'm screwing this up. i'm using a particular flavor of Lex/YACC called GPPG which just sets this all up for use with C#

Here is my Y

```
method      :  L_METHOD L_VALUE ')' { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Found a method: Name:" + $1.Data ); }
            | error { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Not valid in this statement context ");/*Throw new exception*/ }          
            ;
```

here's my Lex

```
\'[^']*\'           {this.yylval.Data = yytext.Replace("'",""); return (int)Tokens.L_VALUE;}
[a-zA-Z0-9]+\(      {this.yylval.Data = yytext; return (int)Tokens.L_METHOD;}
```

The idea is that i should be able to pass
`Method('value')` to it and have it properly recognize that this is correct syntax

ultimately the plan is to execute the `Method` passing the various parameters as values

i've also tried several derivations. for example:

```
 method     :  L_METHOD '(' L_VALUE ')' { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Found a method: Name:" + $1.Data ); }
                | error { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Not valid in this statement context: ");/*Throw new exception*/ }         
                ;

   \'[^']*\'            {this.yylval.Data = yytext.Replace("'",""); return (int)Tokens.L_VALUE;}
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+        {this.yylval.Data = yytext; return (int)Tokens.L_METHOD;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a lex rule to return the punctuation tokens 'as-is' so that the yacc grammar can recognize them.  Something like:

```
[()]        { return *yytext; }
```

added to your second example should do the trick.

Comment: great thanks! i knew it had to be something blindingly simple. For GPPG, it's done like this: 
`[()]   {return (int)yytext[0]; }` to support specific characters.